# Constantly check for object value and end process if false

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm building a control system for a machine with Node on a raspberry pi. There are certain processes that need to stop immediately if one of the safety relays opens. So, I need to checking every 100ms id the safety relays are open, and if they are, send a signal to stop running certain functions.

In general, there will be several functions that need to stop if `Relays.allClosed` becomes false.

```js
var Relays = {
  relay1: false,
  relay2: false,
  allClosed: false,
  checkRelays: function() {
    if (this.relay1 == true && this.relay2 == true) {
      this.allClosed = true
    } else {
      this.allClosed = false
      console.warn("relay open")
    }
  }
}

var safetyCheck = function() { //checks if safety relays are all closed every 100 ms
  setInterval(function() {
    Relays.checkRelays()
  }, 100)
}

safetyCheck()

Machine.run = function(distance) {
  if (Relays.allClosed) { //checks before running the process if the relays are all closed for safety
    // if at any point while running this Relays.allClosed becomes false, function needs to stop running
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('advancing press');
      i++;
      if (i < distance) {
        pressLoop();
      }
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    console.log("can't run machine because one or more safety relay is open")
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just emit an event `realyOpened` and then wait for it? And idlf that is really a "safety relay" i would not write the code in JS.

Comment: `setTimeout` only fires once, you maybe want `setInterval` instead.

Comment: @JonasWilms can you elaborate on both points? emit sounds right but I would need to see an example, thanks

Comment: @Keith yeah, but the solution Jonas mentions is much more efficient and good as a principle.

Comment: What is `//...some stuff` ? Could you add a small sample?

Comment: How do you update `Relays.relay1` / `2` when the state of the physical hardware changes?

Comment: @JonasWilms added sample, @Jamiec haven't gotten that far yet, but going to be using the `onoff` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff

Comment: What about a setter approach? Something like: `set relay({ index, value }) { this[\`relay${index}\`] = value; this.check(); }` and then you would call: `Relays.relay = { index: 1, value: true };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with an event based structure instead like:

```
  const EventEmitter = require('events');

  const input = new EventEmitter();
```

Through that, you can emit events as:

```
 relay1.watch((err, value) => input.emit("relay1", !!value));
```

That way, you can attach a callback to the relay at multiple positions:

```
 input.on("relay1", on => console.log(on));
```

Now to get another event when all relays are on its as easy as:

```
 let relaysCount = 0;
 function updateCount(on) {
   if(on) { 
     relaysCount++;
     if(relaysCount === 2)
       input.emit("allOn");
   } else { 
     relaysCount--;
     input.emit("someOff");
  }
 }

 input.on("relay1", updateCount);
 input.on("relay2", updateCount);
```

Now when starting a timeout like in your example, you can easily cancel that if some are Off:

```
 input.on("allOn", () => {
    const task = setTimeout(/* sth */, 1000);
    input.on("someOff", () => clearTimeout(task));
 });
```

Comment: Any alternative to `watch` since it has been deprecated?

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: @chuckieDub the link you sent?

Comment: I didn't send a link. When I search 'watch' in the docs all I can find is fs.watch https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html

Comment: ah gotcha :) makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is using something like [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) to emit an event when something meaningful happens. This could be a change in state of your `allClosed` value (although I'd argue that your method of continually polling for a changed relay state is an anti-pattern and you should be used event-based logic throughout).

But in any case, assuming an `allClosed` event is raised you can capture that event and stop your running code:

```
Machine.run = function(distance) {
  if (Relays.allClosed) { //checks before running the process if the relays are all closed for safety
    // if at any point while running this Relays.allClosed becomes false, function needs to stop running
    let timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('advancing press');
      i++;
      if (i < distance) {
        pressLoop();
      }
    }, 1000);

    myEventEmitter.on("allClosed", () => {
       clearTimeout(timer);
    })
  } else {
    console.log("can't run machine because one or more safety relay is open")
  }
}
```

This will cancel at the next iteration, but if `pressLoop` is in any way long-running, you should provision for stopping that midway too.

---

The below code illustrates (with buttons in place of physical relays) how you can run the whole thing a series of events.

```js
// just jQuery for mockup - ignore
  $('.relay').on("click", function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("open").toggleClass("closed");
      events.emit("relayChanged", {id:$(this).data("id"), isClosed: $(this).is(".closed")})
  })
  
  
  function RelayMonitor(){
      var relaysClosed = {
         "1": true,
         "2": true
      }
      
      this.init = function(events){
        events.on("relayChanged", (args) => {
            relaysClosed[args.id] = args.isClosed;
            if(Object.values(relaysClosed).every(x => x)) {
                events.emit("allClosed");
            }
        });
      }
  }
  
  //const EventEmitter = require('events'); // included as cdn import here
  var events = new EventEmitter();
  events.on("allClosed", () => console.log("all relays closed"));
var monitor = new RelayMonitor()
monitor.init(events);
```

```css
.closed {
background-color:green
}

.open {
background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.2.5/EventEmitter.js"></script>
<button data-id="1" class="relay closed">Relay1</button>
<button data-id="2" class="relay closed">Relay2</button>
```